# When I Send A Post Request The Response Is Empty

Tags: javascript, express, post, get

I am starting out with express JS with no experience but I got stuck here:

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const users = []

router.get('/getUsers', (req, res) => {
    res.json(users);
});

router.post('/postUsers', (req, res) => {
    const newUser = req.body;
    console.log(newUser);
    users.push(newUser);
    res.json(`${req.body.name} is added`);
});

app.use('/', router);

app.listen(3000);
```

test.rest:

```
###
GET http://localhost:3000/getUsers

###
POST http://localhost:3000/postUsers

{
    "name": "Joseph"
}

###
```

when I make a post request response is: "undefined is added" with a 200 status.

when I make a get request response is :

[

{}

]

with a 200 status

I don't know what is the problem I asked ChatGPT but I wasn't able to solve the problem. Sorry if the question is silly I really didn't understand.

Comment: What does `console.log(newUser);` print?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know which HTTP client you are using, but compare these two tests using cURL:

```bash
curl \
    http://localhost:3000/postUsers \
    --request POST \
    --data '{ "name": "Joseph" }'
```

Outputs:

> "undefined is added"

```bash
curl \
    http://localhost:3000/postUsers \
    --request POST \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{ "name": "Joseph" }'
```

Outputs:

> "Joseph is added"

The [Content-Type request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) describes the format of the request body.

There's no sign of a `Content-Type` header in your `test.rest` file, and given the behaviour matches the test of mine which omits it, its a pretty good bet that that is your problem.

You are POSTing JSON, but you've failed to tell the server that the payload *is* JSON.

Express middleware, including `express.json`, tends to use the content-type to decide if it should try to parse the request body. (Keep in mind that you might have *multiple* body parsing middlewares in a system that can handle different formats of request body.)

Since your request doesn't specify the content-type, `express.json` doesn't try to parse it, and the body is a blank object.

I'd *guess* the format you need would be:

```
###
GET http://localhost:3000/getUsers

###
POST http://localhost:3000/postUsers
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name": "Joseph"
}

###
```